# AccessViolationException in QuickFIX when session reset

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm not that FIX expert, and I have a code that must be solved by me...

Everyday, at 2am my time (which is 00:00:00 FIX server time), the application that I have crash due to access violation exception in QuickFix. This is the error from the Event Viewer:

```
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException Stack: at <Module>.FIX.Initiator.stop(FIX.Initiator*, Boolean) at QuickFix.SocketInitiator.stop(Boolean) at QuickFix.SocketInitiator.Dispose(Boolean) at QuickFix.SocketInitiator.Finalize()
```

The application is written in C# with QuickFix.

Any clues to guide me where to proceed? Is it something with QuickFIX?

Any guide will be highly appreciate, am in the middle of no where!

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with QuickFix. Can you post your config ? And what is happening before the crash happens ? I would assume something wrong with how the socket is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this lines to your app.config, you can catch the error with try catch block and you can investigate the error

```
  <runtime>
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
```

It should be placed just before `</configuration>` tag.